# Injectivity radius of the completion of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Dear members, 
Given an open manifold $M$ and its completion $\bar{M}$, do we have $inj(M)=inj(\bar{M})$,
Thank you
Riadh

Comment: When the completion is not a manifold, how do you define its injectivity radius?

Comment: In any case, it seems to me that the injectivity radius of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite and the injectivity radius of $\mathbb{R}\backslash{0}$ is zero.

Comment: If the injectivity radius is strictly positive the metric is automatically complete. 

Comment: @MohanRamachandran: Is the converse true?